# jetty 9.1.0.v20131115 / OSX 0.7.5 / Oracle jdk 1.7

Tags: java, macos, jetty

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.
I have jetty 9 working fine on an Ubuntu 12.04 VM.

I'm now trying to run the same jetty on my MacBook pro.
But its running incredibly slowly and the websockets demos don't work.

So its gotta be something about the install of my MacBook.
As I said in the subject its running Lion (10.7.5) and I have just installed jre-7u45-macosx-x64.dmg onto the machine.

When I do java -version I get

```
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

I have untarred jetty and when I cd down into the demo-base folder I just do:

```
java -jar ../start.jar
```

And then point Chrome at `http://localhost:8080` and navigate to the demos

I'm finding that the navigation is way slower than it is on the Ubuntu box and the websockets demos are just non-functional.

I'm not sure what direction to go in now to tease this out, so would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Use `jvisualvm` to see where the most time is spent. That may give you something to google for or ask about.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to start jvisualvm but it comes up blank and a load of errors appear on the command line: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0 and CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0. When I click on the jvisualvm window it redirects me to a browser window called Visual VM Troubleshooting guide...

Comment: The "invalid context" errors are a regular occurence and usually harmless. They may or may not be related to your problem. But now it looks like you have a more general Java installation issue.

Comment: Just wondering.. I installed jre-7u45-macosx-x64.dmg but java -version gives me 1.7.0_05 not _45.. is there something in that at all?

Comment: Yes, that's a problem. Just installing a newer JDK doesn't mean its `java` command is being used. Check with `ls -l \`which java\` ` to see where the symbolic link is pointing to, and follow through.

Comment: Ok.. so its using the java at: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java

Comment: Hmmm.. weird.. I installed 1.7 but when I ls the versions folder (/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions) I don't get a symlink to a 1.7 version.. instead I get:   1.4@        1.4.2@      1.5@        1.5.0@      1.6@        1.6.0@      A/          Current@    CurrentJDK@ - and the CurrentJDK symlink points to /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents

Comment: I see a link that might solve it, but its for Mountain Lion.... http://www.monkehworks.com/set-java-7-as-default-jvm-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41886/discussion-between-user1844711-and-marko-topolnik)

Comment: Drat.. problem was I installed JRE but not JDK.

Comment: The path you have indicated is where *Apple's* Java is installed, so apparently installing just the JRE from Oracle didn't even try to update the path entries. What I find myself doing regurarly is `cd /usr/bin; sudo ln -sf <path_to_Oracle_java_bin_dir>/* .`.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I was stupid.
I installed the JRE and not the JDK.
When I installed the JDK it all started working.
Apologies for any time wasted.
Thanks to Marko for time spent trying to help me.